# Running PHP/MySQL website from USB drive

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, xampp, usb-drive

PROBLEM:

I've got a client who needs to run their website(uses PHP/MySQL/Apache) from a USB thumb drive on both Windows and Mac, even Linux if possible. So they could plug the USB thumb into a Windows machine and the sites index would load, alternatively plug the thumb into a Mac or Linux machine and voilà the site index loads.

To clarify further, my client essentially wants to distribute these USB thumb drives to his own clients so they can browse a sample group of products uniquely catered too them. This would mean the launching of the site from the USB thumb drive would need to be as simple as possible since no assumptions can be made about the clients technical know how! A a double click and go type solution would be ideal if auto load isn't an option. Is this achievable with a Virtual Machine solution as suggested below in the comments? Or would some software such as VMware Player need to be installed on the clients machine first in order for a Virtual Machine on the USB to be launched?

FINDINGS:

I've managed to get XAMPP Portable Lite installed and running from a USB thumb via Windows 7, however I obviously cannot start XAMPP Portable Lite when connecting the USB to a Mac / Linux system. I've tried installing and running XAMPP for Mac from the USB also, however it can't seem to run outside of the Mac's /Applications directory.

If anyone could please shed some light on a possible way to achieve what my client is wanting using XAMPP or anything else, or whether it's even possible, I would be grateful!!

PS: I noticed there is a solution which would achieve what my client is wanting offered by a company called Stunnix, however they charge a fairly hefty fee, so I'm holding off in the hope a freeware solution to my clients problem exists somewhere.

Comment: Would something like [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) be an option? Build a VM and distribute that.

Comment: I have done this, although it takes one more step than you require I believe.  I imaged a bootable LINUX distro (Ubuntu 11.4) onto a USB drive.  This image included Apache and all the modules I needed for PHP and MySQL.  The caveat is that you have to reboot the PC to your USB drive, and reboot back when finished.

Comment: @Zak, No need for reboot, use VMWare Player or something similar.

Comment: @ Brad, I've never looked at it from that angle ... clever

Comment: VMWare Player is free. Oracle VirtualBox is also free. The player is probably easier to use, but VirtualBox can be scripted.

Comment: Stupid question of mine I bet, but couldn't they use a remote server instead?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, PHP, MySQL, and Apache all run just fine on all three platforms.  Just include statically compiled x86 copies for both platforms, and you're good to go.

Now, as far as the autorun problem goes, there is nothing you can do about that.  Almost no system these days will automatically run executables upon inserting removable media.

Comment: good to go? Good luck binding to port 80 on Linux w/o root then :)

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com, Heh, perhaps I should clarify.  By "good to go" I mean "it should be trivial to open a terminal window and run your scripts".  I do not intend to say that this is some magical solution.  Of course there are hurdles.  What he wants simply isn't possible.  Tadman's VM solution is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

In general - no, you can't get all-in-one solution. There's too big differences incl. approach to security on these platforms. It's simpler on Windows, while you face more problems on Linux due to security models (like protecting bind to ports <1024). In general, you may need to end with virtualization, if that would suffice for your needs.